# Swapping a specific character in a char array with another character java

Tags: java, swap, arrays

it has been 8 years since I last programmed, and then it was just basics for a networking degree. I am writing a basic program to start my way back into java programming. the program is dealing with binary numbers stored as strings.

e.g. `01101110010`

I have got everything else working, but now I want to swap all "1" for "0" and all "0" for "1"

to get `10010001101`

The problem is the only way I know to swap chars is to create a new string with the chars replaced but I can only do one char at a time and then I just end up with a string of all `1`s or `0`s

so I thought about using a char array and trying to swap each char in the array but I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Post your code and perhaps someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
String str = "0101010101110";
char[] cs = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++)
{
    if (cs[i] == '1')
        cs[i] = '0';
    else if (cs[i] == '0')
        cs[i] = '1';
}
str = new String(cs);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the method you use is open you could use [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
String str = "01101110010";
System.out.println(str.replace("1", "X").replace("0", "1").replace("X", "0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "01101110010".replace("0", "*").replace("1", "0").replace("*", "1");
```